# Can't zoom using phtoImage in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I'm trying to zoom in & out, in a canvas. But when I zoom, the canvas still empty. [Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORcuj.png)

## teste.py

```
from tkinter import *
from observable import *

class Model(Observable):

    def __init__(self):
        Observable.__init__(self)

        self.scale = 1

        File = "image.png"

        self.orig_img = PhotoImage(file = File)

    def zoom(self,event): # window binded width "<MouseWheel>"
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.scale += 1
        elif event.delta < 0:
            self.scale -= 1

        self._docallUpdate(self)

class View(Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master)

    def update(self, model):
        self.delete("all")
        if model.scale > 0:
            img = model.orig_img.zoom(model.scale)
        elif model.scale < 0:
            img = model.orig_img.subsample(abs(model.scale))
        else: img = model.orig_img
        print(img)

        self.create_image(0, 0, image= img, anchor = "nw")
```

## Observers.py

```
class Observable:

    def __init__(self):
        self.observers = {}

    def addObserver(self, ob):
        self.observers[ob] = 1

    def delObserver(self, element):
        del self.observers[element]

    def _docallUpdate(self, mod):
        for ob in self.observers:
             ob.update(mod)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to copy/paste your code and share with us the error messages you get from it

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ The code is a screenshot. And the problem is that there are no error messages, just when i use canvas.create_image, the canvas still empty

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ i found the problem : in the class View in update replace every "img" by "self.img" but could you explain me why ?

Comment: You need a _global_ reference to images or they get garbage collected, aka removed from memory. Learn more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424091/7032856). `self.img` is a global reference whereas `img` is a _local_ variable, aka only available under `view` method.